# Custom View constructor in Android 4.4 crashes on Kotlin, how to fix?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a custom view written in Kotlin using JvmOverloads that I could have default value.

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes)
```

All works fine in Android 5.1 and above.

However it crashes in 4.4, since the constructor in 4.4 doesn't have `defStyleRes`. How could I have that supported that in 5.1 and above I could have `defStyleRes` but not in 4.4, without need to explicitly having 4 constructors defined like we did in Java?

Note: The below would works fine in 4.4, but then we loose the `defStyleRes`.

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle)
```

Comment: You can read a bit more about the side effects of `@JvmOverloads` in this article:
https://medium.com/@mmlodawski/https-medium-com-mmlodawski-do-not-always-trust-jvmoverloads-5251f1ad2cfe

Answer (score 15):

Best way is to have your class this way.

```
class MyView : LinearLayout {
    @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
}
```

Comment: That's back to the old way of having all 4 constructors defined :(

Comment: Well it's the way Android Works, no matter how much Kotlin's syntax helps, it's Android the one which requires Boilerplate :D Anyways, you can trim these down using default values, but you have to use at least 2 constructors

Comment: @Elye I have edited my answer to show same functionality with 2 constructors

Comment: Hi, that's the same as per what my question is. It will crash in 4.4

Comment: Well of course it will crash if you use the second constructor on 4.4

Comment: Cool. just see your answer. Perhaps would need to wrap with @TargetApi?

Comment: Yes sure, I will add it. Don't forget to mark it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

I got a way of doing so. Just overload the first 3 functions will do, leave the 4th one for Lollipop and above wrap with @TargetApi.

```
class MyView : LinearLayout {
    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
        : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int)
        : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
}
```

Comment: This a valid answer. Good @Elye

Comment: How do you access attrs inside the init function with this approach @Elye?

Comment: @niegus you can, just make your own `initialize` function al call it

Answer (score 1):

Just define the constructors like this:

```
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
@TargetApi(21)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
```